# Alternative method for Creation Order Summary

Tags: apex, commerce-cloud, connect-api, b2b-commerce

My requirement was to create test class for Creating Order Summary. Test data was created using ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary. But if I use ConnectApi, I was forced to use (SellAllData=true) which is not a good practice in test class. Is there any other way to create Order Summary record without ConnectApi Or How can I know what is inside ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.

This is how I tried to create OrderSummary using ConnectApi:

```
ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation osir= new ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation();
            osir.orderId=od.Id;
            osir.orderLifeCycleType='Managed';
     
ConnectApi.OrderSummaryOutputRepresentation osor= ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary(osir);

OrderSummary orderSum=[SELECT Id, OriginalOrderId, OwnerId FROM OrderSummary WHERE OriginalOrderId =:od.Id];

List<String> osId=new List<String>();
osId.add(orderSum.Id);
```

Comment: You can leverage the flow that usually creates the Order Summary at Order activation.
Create an Order in draft status in your test class + all related data. Then update it to Activated status, this would trigger your flow for Order Summary creation

Answer (score 0):

Previous answer is 100% ChatGPT-generated. Unfortunately, AI is not aware about that particular case and will not help you.

```
Account acc = new Account(Name = 'Test');
insert acc;
Pricebook2 pb = [
    SELECT Id
      FROM Pricebook2
     WHERE isStandard = true
     LIMIT 1
];
Order order = new Order(
    AccountId = acc.Id,
    // SalesStoreId = cart.WebStoreId,
    // PoNumber = cart.PoNumber,
    // BillingStreet = cart.BillingStreet,
    // BillingCity = cart.BillingCity,
    // BillingState = cart.BillingState,
    // BillingPostalCode = cart.BillingPostalCode,
    // BillingCountry = cart.BillingCountry,
    // BillingLatitude = cart.BillingLatitude,
    // BillingLongitude = cart.BillingLongitude,
    Pricebook2Id = pb.Id,
    EffectiveDate = Date.today(),
    OrderedDate = Date.today(),
    Status = 'Draft'
);
insert(order);
OrderDeliveryMethod m = new OrderDeliveryMethod();
m.Name = 'Test';
insert m;
OrderDeliveryGroup orderDeliveryGroup = new OrderDeliveryGroup(
    Description = 'cartDeliveryGroup.Description',
    DesiredDeliveryDate = Date.today(),
    DeliverToName = 'cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToName',
    DeliveryInstructions = 'cartDeliveryGroup.ShippingInstructions',
    // DeliverToStreet = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToStreet,
    // DeliverToCity = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToCity,
    // DeliverToState = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToState,
    // DeliverToPostalCode = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToPostalCode,
    // DeliverToCountry = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToCountry,
    // DeliverToLatitude = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToLatitude,
    // DeliverToLongitude = cartDeliveryGroup.DeliverToLongitude,
    OrderDeliveryMethodId = m.Id,
    OrderId = order.Id
);
insert orderDeliveryGroup;
Product2 prod = new Product2(name = 'Test');
insert prod;
/*Pricebook2 pb = new Pricebook2(
    Name = 'Example Price Book',
    Description = 'This is the Price Book description.',
    IsActive = true,
    IsStandard = true
);
insert pb;*/

PricebookEntry pbe = new PricebookEntry(
    Pricebook2Id = pb.Id,
    Product2Id = prod.Id,
    UnitPrice = 1,
    IsActive = true,
    UseStandardPrice = false
);
insert pbe;
OrderItem orderItem = new OrderItem(
    Product2Id = prod.Id,
    // Type = orderItemType,
    Quantity = 1,
    ListPrice = 1,
    UnitPrice = 1,
    OrderId = order.Id,
    PricebookEntryId = pbe.Id,
    OrderDeliveryGroupId = orderDeliveryGroup.Id
    // TotalLineAmount = cartItem.TotalLineAmount
);
insert(orderItem);
order.Status = 'Activated';
update order;
ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation osir = new
    ConnectApi.OrderSummaryInputRepresentation();
osir.orderId=order.Id; //replace this recordId with an appropriate value.
osir.orderLifeCycleType='UNMANAGED';
ConnectApi.OrderSummaryOutputRepresentation osor =
    ConnectApi.OrderSummaryCreation.createOrderSummary(osir);
```

This code is not ideal but it works. Use it to create OrderSummary record.